# Static views contents on dynamic routes

Tags: node.js, routes, express

How come the image file in my `classroom.ejs` is not showing if I use this

```
app.configure(function() { 
   //app.use('/room1',express.static(__dirname+'/public')); 
   app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
   app.set('views', __dirname + '/public'); 
});

app.get('/room1/:nickname', function(req, res){ 
   res.render('classroom.ejs', {title: req.params.nickname});
});
```

If I uncomment the `app.use('/room1',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));`

It works.
I need the static files to pull from `/public` regardless of the route and given the fact that its on top,
it should have top priority. I'm using Express 3.0.x

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
var path = require('path');
...
app.use(app.router);
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: i get the same. all i have in my app.configure is  app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');  
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: why do you need `app.use('/room1',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));`?

Comment: its the only way the image would show inside /room1/:nickname . im thinking if you just have app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public')); then all css, js, and static files would already pull from root directory /public and thus not need app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));. but that is not the case. can we make this global so that regardless of the dynamic route, all css, js, and images will use /public as the root directory and not have to declare app.use('/someroute',express.static(__dirname+'/public'));